# How can I remove the first and last characters from a string?

Tags: javascript

Example :

```
let a = 'hello'
```

Select the first and last characters from the string and remove them.

```
console.log(a);

//expected output 

ell
```

Comment: `slice()` works here: `console.log(a.slice(1,-1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `slice`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

In your case, this should work:

```js
a.slice(1, -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also help:

```
let a = 'hello'
a.substring(1, a.length - 1)
```

For more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/substring

Answer (score 2):

Use the javascript slice function.

`a.slice(1, a.length)`

Look up the javascript slice function.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding splice, slice, substring...

```
const word = 'hello'
const filtered =
  word
  .split('')
  .filter((x, i) => !(i === 0 || i === word.length - 1))
  .join('');

console.log(filtered)
```